# Every 4th element addclass doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I have a script that dynamically builds some html. The html is then appended to 3 tabpages.

I'm trying to add a class to every 4th element that is build. It works for the first two tabpages but not for the third one. I'm really confused.... Any help greatly appreciated!

```
function tabs(page,targetClass){ // targetClass = the div to append to
    $.getJSON('http://test.com/'+page+'/page.ajax', function(json){   

        var productsHtml = [];

        $.each(json.products, function(index, product){

            $('.productout:nth-child(4n)').addClass('last');

            var productHtml = '' +
                '<div class="productout">..... etc</div>';

            productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');

        $(targetClass).html(productsHtml);

    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the class after the new elements are added to the dom.

```
function tabs(page, targetClass) { // targetClass = the div to append to
    $.getJSON('http://test.com/' + page + '/page.ajax', function (json) {
        var productsHtml = [];

        $.each(json.products, function (index, product) {
            var productHtml = '' +
                '<div class="productout">..... etc</div>';
            productsHtml.push(productHtml);
        });
        productsHtml = productsHtml.join('');
        //after the products html is added to the dom find the `productout` elements and add the desired class
        $(targetClass).html(productsHtml).find('.productout:nth-child(4n)').addClass('last');
    });
}
```

Comment: To clarify: before you add the elements to the DOM, they aren't the children of anything, so they won't ever match the `:nth-child(4n)` selector.

Comment: @Arun P Johny: That makes perfect sense. Didn't come up with the solution 'find' and then 'addClass'.... Awesome thx for your time