# Why can't I style every 2nd element with this CSS?

Tags: css

I'm working with this HTML structure:

```
<section class="portfolio">
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div>
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div> 
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div> 
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div>
</section>
```

I am trying to change the background colour of **every second figure** with CSS as follows:

```
section.portfolio a:nth-type(odd) figure {
  background: white smoke;
}
```

**Please note**

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607386/every-4th-element-addclass-doesnt-work), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860786/style-every-third-element) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27388289/css-select-every-2nd-element-in-mixed-list) similar question, however if I apply their answers it's still not working and I am confused why. I am clearly doing something wrong I just don't understand what it is....

**I have tried:**

```
section.portfolio a :nth-type(odd) figure {
  background: white smoke;
}
```

```
section.portfolio a :nth-child(odd) figure {
  background: white smoke;
}
```

```
section.portfolio a figure:nth-child(odd) {
  background: white smoke;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant `nth-of-type(odd)` and `whitesmoke` but not `white smoke`, see if it is what you want.

```css
section.portfolio a:nth-of-type(4n+1) figure {
  background: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div>
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div> 
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div> 
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
  <div>Blurb</div>  
  <a href="example">
    <figure>
      <img src="example">
      <figcaption>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
      </figcaption>
    </figure> 
  </a>
</section>
```

Comment: how would get every 4th? or every 8th? when I go (n4+1) or (n8+1) I get nothing... I thought I understood this but it seems I have to educate myself a bit more here

Comment: I edited the above code to show how `4n+1` will work.

Comment: Gosh I need some sleep ^-^ I now see I wrongly placed the 'n' many thanks